# Connect xy points with spatial lines

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, spatial, lines, points

I have a dataset of XY points that looks like this

```
x<-c(2,4,6,3,7,9,1)
y<-c(6,4,8,2,9,6,1)
id<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
dataset<-data.frame(cbind(x,y,id))
```

I would like to connect *all combinations of all points* with spatial lines, with lines named with combinations of the points that they're connecting

In "attributes table" that results from the output, names for spatial lines might look like this:

```
a_b
a_c
a_d
a_e
a_f
a_g
b_a
b_c
b_d
b_e
b_f
b_g
c_a
etc.
```

Comment: `combn(id, 2, FUN = function(x) paste(x, collapse = "_"))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm speculating a bit here as to what exactly you wanted, but I think you want to visualize the connections from any point to the others. If that's the case, then this might work.
But first, some assumptions:

- Your `x` and `y` coordinates are starting points. Consequently, `id` are thus `id.origin`
- All other points will need to become "destinations", and then their own coordinates will become `x_destination` and so on.

< disclaimer> There **should be** a better, more elegant way to do this. I'd appreciate if someone more experienced can jump in and show me any of the `*ply` ways to do it. < /disclaimer>

Replicate the dataframe to cover for all possible combinations

```
dataset<-do.call(rbind, replicate(7, dataset, simplify=FALSE))
```

Now, create a matrix with all the same destination points, mixed:

```
nm=matrix(ncol=3)
for (i in 1:7){
    nm<-rbind(nm,do.call(rbind,replicate(7,as.matrix(dataset[i,]),simplify=FALSE)))
}
nm<-nm[-1,]
```

Rename the columns of matrix, so they make sense, and bind the existing data frame with the new matrix

```
colnames(nm)<-c("x2","y2","id.dest")
newds<-cbind(dataset,as.data.frame(nm))
```

Remove duplicated trajectories:

```
newds<-newds[-which(newds$id.origin==newds$id.dest),]
```

and plot the result using `geom_segment`:

```
p<-ggplot(newds,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_segment(aes(xend=x2,yend=y2))
```

There is a way to name the segments, but from observing the plot I would't suggest doing it. Instead you might consider naming the points using `geom_text` (other options are available, see `?annotate` for one).

```
p<-p + geom_text(aes(x=1.8,y=6.1,label="a"))
```

That will produce a plot like the one here:
[image: Quiver-like plot of distances]

Comment: Good stuff @PavoDive - thank you. This creates the lines for sure. Can be combined with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531066/convert-begin-and-end-coordinates-into-spatial-lines-in-r to make the points into [spatial lines].

Answer (score 3):

The whole solution looks like this:

```
plot(dataset$x,dataset$y)
```

Replicate the dataframe to cover for all possible combinations

```
dataset<-do.call(rbind, replicate(7, dataset, simplify=FALSE))
```

Now, create a matrix with all the same destination points, mixed:

```
nm=matrix(ncol=3)
for (i in 1:7){
  nm<-rbind(nm,do.call(rbind,replicate(7,as.matrix(dataset[i,]),simplify=FALSE)))
}
nm<-nm[-1,]
```

Rename the columns of matrix, so they make sense, and bind the existing data frame with the new matrix

```
colnames(nm)<-c("x2","y2","id.dest")
newds<-cbind(dataset,as.data.frame(nm))
```

Remove duplicated trajectories:

```
newds1<-newds[-which(newds$id==newds$id.dest),]

library(ggplot2)
```

Converting destination x & y to numeric from factor

```
newds1$x2<-as.numeric(as.character(newds1$x2)) #converting from factor to numeric
newds1$y2<-as.numeric(as.character(newds1$y2))
```

Plotting the destination points . . .same as the origin points

```
plot(newds1$x, newds1$y) 
plot(newds1$x2, newds1$y2, col="red")
```

Now use code from this answer:

**[Convert Begin and End Coordinates into Spatial Lines in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531066/convert-begin-and-end-coordinates-into-spatial-lines-in-r)**

Raw list to store Lines objects:

```
l <- vector("list", nrow(newds1)) #
```

This `l` is now an empty vector w/ number of rows defined by length (nrow) of newds1

Splitting origin and destination coordinates so I can run this script:

```
origins<-data.frame(cbind(newds1$x, newds1$y))
destinations<-data.frame(cbind(newds1$x2, newds1$y2))

library(sp)
for (i in seq_along(l)) {
  l[[i]] <- Lines(list(Line(rbind(origins[i, ], destinations[i,]))), as.character(i))
}

l.spatial<-SpatialLines(l)
plot(l.spatial, add=T)
```