# Calculate nearest point coordinate and distance by differing years between two data frames using sf

Tags: r, coordinates, distance, r-sf, nearest-neighbor

For each observation in a data frame in a year I am trying to finde the nearest observation in another data frame one year prior and calculate their distance.

Following this (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349955/getting-a-new-column-with-distance-to-the-nearest-feature-in-r) approach, I wrote the following code:

```
for(x in 2000:2020) {
  R36_loc$nearest <- st_nearest_points(
    R36_loc %>% ungroup() %>% filter(year == x),
    mining_loc %>% ungroup() %>% filter(year == x - 1)
  )
}
R36_loc$dist_near_mine = st_distance(R36_loc, mining_loc[nearest,], by_element=TRUE)
```

My data looks like this: `mining_loc`:

```
structure(list(year = structure(c(2009, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2007, 
2007, 2009, 2008, 2010, 2008, 2011, 2002, 2012, 2012, 2009, 2010, 
2012, 2006, 2014, 2013, 2008, 2010, 2006, 2011, 2004, 2006, 2011, 
2012, 2014, 2005), label = "year", format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    geometry = structure(list(structure(c(29.6789, -3.5736), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(29.146988, -26.09538), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(0.089167, 35.93111), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(29.915396, -20.535308), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(28.01295, -26.22712), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-8.88214, 31.86011), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(6.475727, 30.66071), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-2.04396, 5.243666), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(27.702666, -21.358855), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(48.650001, -16.176654), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(33.23611, 28.59167), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(30.945726, -22.507772), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(22.90999, -27.175352), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(10.44916725, 35.54916763), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-12.136052, 7.765232), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(32.89942, 24.09082), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(28.58115, -25.256046), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(31.673825, -28.221349), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(12.916667, 18.683333), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(8.915834, 33.53159), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(17.71667, -19.21667), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(27.88332939, -12.46667004), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(33.98638, 17.70217), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(27.302793, -25.65206), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-8.10837, 6.87479), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-5.03293, 31.50764), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(38.66667, -3.81667), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(27.191434, -27.390284), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(31.924721, -28.841876), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-10.7299, 11.32676), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -12.136052, 
    ymin = -28.841876, xmax = 48.650001, ymax = 35.93111), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
        input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), class = c("sf", 
"grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), groups = structure(list(year = structure(c(2002, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014), label = "year", format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    .rows = structure(list(12L, 25L, 30L, c(18L, 23L, 26L), c(2L, 
    5L, 6L), c(3L, 8L, 10L, 21L), c(1L, 4L, 7L, 15L), c(9L, 16L, 
    22L), c(11L, 24L, 27L), c(13L, 14L, 17L, 28L), 20L, c(19L, 
    29L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), .drop = TRUE), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(year = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
```

and `R36_loc`:

```
structure(list(year = c(2012, 2013, 2008, 2005, 2012, 2013, 2005, 
2013, 2008, 2005, 2012, 2012, 2008, 2005, 2005, 2009, 2008, 2012, 
2005, 2006, 2012, 2005, 2008, 2012, 2012, 2005, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2005), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(29.17557, -21.20929
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-13.75231, 9.4795399
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-8.5474997, 
6.82056), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-23.522779, 
14.91389), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-2.64236, 
7.8043299), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(40.041, 
-0.17200001), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(33.48946, 
-9.1142197), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-7.07623, 
4.6770301), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(34.116669, 
-14.15), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(35.650669, 
-15.80635), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-11.01406, 
6.6858401), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(34.030159, 
0.84144002), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(34.191002, 
1.016), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(37.385761, 
-1.94943), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(2.23564, 
7.8688698), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(29.5, 
-18.75), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(36.803509, 
-14.32926), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(25.883329, 
-24.48333), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(26.987329, 
-16.688841), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(25.636339, 
-33.974258), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-11.133, 
6.8152399), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(35.416672, 
-4.1500001), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(28.75, 
-30), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(57.633331, 
-20.41667), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(33.5, 
-3.6666701), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(35.27496, 
-0.56010997), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3.30757, 
6.63937), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-13.647, 
13.605), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(32.209759, 
-2.80952), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(36.71236, 
1.78276), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -23.522779, 
ymin = -33.974258, xmax = 57.633331, ymax = 14.91389), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("sf", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(year = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
```

Each observation from `R36_loc` should show the distance to the nearest observation in `mining_loc` on year prior in a new variable.

The first error I get, I think, is due to some years not having any observations (Error in UseMethod("st_as_sfc") :   no applicable method for 'st_as_sfc' applied to an object of class "NULL").

When I only loop through existing years I get

```
Error:
! Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 7207 rows.
✖ Assigned data has 352800 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Backtrace:
  1. base::`$<-`(`*tmp*`, nearest, value = `<GEOMETRY [°]>`)
 19. tibble (local) `<fn>`(`<vctrs___>`)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this using the `RANN` package.
I start by extracting the geometry to long and lat columns and converting my data frame to a list of data frames by year:

```
R36_loc2 <- R36_loc %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(long = unlist(map(.$geometry,1)),
           lat = unlist(map(.$geometry,2)))
st_geometry(R36_loc2) <- NULL

AB_by_year <- split(R36_loc2, f = R36_loc$year)
```

Since, for the second data frame, I need the observations from a year prior, I create a new year variable `merge_year` and also transform the data into a list by the new variable:

```
mining_loc$merge_year <- mining_loc$year - 1
# make list of data by merging year
mining_by_year <- split(mining_loc, f = mining_loc$merge_year)
# make ID var
mining_by_year <- mining_by_year %>% lapply(function(x) {x %>% rowid_to_column("ID")})
```

I then loop through the years and look for closest mine to each observation in each year - merge_year - combination, then add two new columns `[ , c(43,44)]` to each year data frame in the AB-list of data frames.
The two columns will indicate the ID of closest mine to each observation in the corresponding year-dataframe in the mining_list, called `nn.idx`, and the distance, called `nn.dists`.

```
for(x in wave_years) {
  AB_by_year[[as.character(x)]][ , c(43,44)] <- as.data.frame(RANN::nn2(mining_by_year[[as.character(x)]][,c("lat", "long")], AB_by_year[[as.character(x)]][,c("lat", "long")], k=1)
  )
}
```

I then check if it worked, by creating maps that connect the observations to the mines.

I first create a list for the lines to nearest mine

```
lines_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(wave_years))
names(lines_list) <- wave_years
```

I joint the observations with each nearest mine coordinates

```
for(x in wave_years) {
  lines_list[[as.character(x)]] <- left_join(AB_by_year[[as.character(x)]], mining_by_year[[as.character(x)]], by = c("nn.idx" = "ID"))
}
```

I then need to convert the list back to a data frame:

```
lines <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lines_list)
```

and now I follow the approach of: [Connecting two sets of coordinates to create lines using sf/mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187057/connecting-two-sets-of-coordinates-to-create-lines-using-sf-mapview?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
b = lines[, c("long.x", "lat.x")]
names(b) = c("long", "lat")
e = lines[, c("long.y", "lat.y")]
names(e) = c("long", "lat")

lines$geometry = do.call(
  "c", 
  lapply(seq(nrow(b)), function(i) {
    st_sfc(
      st_linestring(
        as.matrix(
          rbind(b[i, ], e[i, ])
        )
      ),
      crs = 4326
    )
  }))
```

Finally, I want to show graphically, that the code worked by first converting the data into sf-objects

```
mining_loc_geo <- st_as_sf(mining_loc, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)
R36_loc_geo <- st_as_sf(R36_loc, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)
```

and then plotting them with ggplot.

```
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = boundaries_africa3, aes()) + geom_sf(data = R36_loc_geo %>% filter(year == 2005), color = "blue", aes(geometry = geometry)) + geom_sf(data = mining_loc_geo %>% filter(merge_year == 2005), color = "red", aes(geometry = geometry)) + geom_sf(data = lines %>% filter(year.x == 2005), aes(geometry = geometry))
```

The object `boundaries_africa3` is an underlying map.