# Estimating distance between points and its relative elevation for multiple countries and geometries, using R sf

Tags: r, geospatial, elevation

I have multiple points (lon, lat) for a range of countries. These points are related by an ID that when connected creates a line.

**data exmaple:**

```
 aus:
 id   country  point_id      lon       lat
  1  Australia        0 130.1491 -19.57520
  1  Australia        1 129.9958 -19.48760
  1  Australia        2 129.7156 -19.25788
  1  Australia        3 129.7104 -19.20223
  2  Australia        0 129.2510 -18.59016
  2  Australia        1 129.5436 -18.30723
  3  Australia        0 137.2840 -20.06129
  3  Australia        1 137.2865 -20.04308
  3  Australia        2 137.1915 -20.00782
  3  Australia        3 137.1220 -19.97166
  3  Australia        4 137.0650 -19.91363
  3  Australia        5 136.8961 -19.85932
  4  Australia        0 136.8961 -19.85932
  4  Australia        1 136.8791 -19.88669
  4  Australia        2 136.8594 -19.91227
  4  Australia        3 136.8454 -19.92507
  4  Australia        4 136.8360 -19.92976
```

I managed to create the geometry following this post [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187057/connecting-two-sets-of-coordinates-to-create-lines-using-sf-mapview)], however, I think my attempt can be automated further. I attempted using group by individually, as follow:

**attempt 1 to get linestrings:**

```
# same logic as in [1] but by group
aus_group <- aus %>% group_by(id, country) 

b_group <- aus %>% group_by(id, country) %>% select(lon, lat)
e_group <- aus %>% group_by(id, country) %>% filter(row_number()!=1) %>% select(lon, lat)
f_group <- e_group %>% group_by(id, country) %>% summarise_all(last) %>% select(country, lon, lat)
g_group <- e_group %>% group_by(id, country) %>% rbind(f_group) %>% arrange(id)

aus_group$geometry = do.call(
  "c", 
  lapply(seq(nrow(b_group)), function(i) {
    st_sfc(
      st_linestring(
        as.matrix(
          rbind(b_group[i, c("lon", "lat")], g_group[i, c("lon", "lat")])
          )
        ),
      crs = 4326
      )
    }))

dat_g_sf = st_as_sf(aus_group)
mapview(dat_g_sf, zcol = "id")

# to compare with approach in [1]
dat_g_sf %>% filter(id==1) %>% mapview(zcol = "point_id") # got same plot
# so it works
```

I share this part in case there are suggestions to improve the group_by part

**question:**

My actual question is regarding distance estimation between points and the relative elevation between those points.

For the distance estimation, I have tried this:

**attempt 2 to get distances:**

```
# edited aus_1 becomes aus
aus_2 <- aus %>% select(id, country, point_id, lon, lat) #to avoid error with geometry
str(aus_2)
aus_2$distance = do.call(
  "c", 
  lapply(seq(nrow(b)), function(i) {
    st_distance(
      st_sfc(st_point
# edited b becomes b_group, and g becomes g_group
             (as.matrix(rbind(b_group[i, c("lon", "lat")], g_group[i, c("lon", "lat")], by_element = TRUE)
               )
             ),
      crs = 4326
      )
    }))
Error in st_point(as.matrix(rbind(b_group[i, c("lon", "lat")], g_group[i, c("lon", "lat")]), by_element = TRUE)) : 
nrow(x) == 1 is not TRUE
```

I think the error might be related with the matrix creation. I appreciate any help here.

**expected results:** edited.

As can be seen in my **attempt 2**, I tried to get the length between points (by point_id), e.g., distance between point_id: 0 & 1, in id: 1; and so on; using *st_distance*. (I guess the sum of all distances by point_id would result on the total length estimation).

In my understanding, the distance for point_id == 0 should be zero because it is the distance between point_id: 0 and 0, while the distance between point_id: 0 and 1 is the actual distance for point_id: 1. This is the reason why in my **attempt 1 and 2**, I tried to create two groups of c("lon", "lat"): b_group and g_group, and then I try applying *st_distance* between point b and point g. Unfortunately, this did not work.

Overall: it is expected "an sf object of point geometries with the same number of rows as an input dataset, with distance to lagging or leading point (between point_id) within the same group (id) + elevation (between by point_id)" from [margusl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646761/margusl) comment.

no edited:

For the relative elevation estimation, I haven’t found previous work on this using R. Suggestions regarding where to start about elevation estimation are welcome.

Also, what is the meaning of "c" in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187057/connecting-two-sets-of-coordinates-to-create-lines-using-sf-mapview)? How does it work in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For elevation you'd need some data source / provider. `elevatr` package potentially can provide you values for point locations, for example through  *[Amazon Web Service Terrain Tiles](https://registry.opendata.aws/terrain-tiles/)*, but you'd probably need to evaluate those results and work out acceptable resolution / zoom levels, `elevatr` docs should cover this part.

To get distances between every current and previous point, you can use  element-wise distance with lag:

```r
library(elevatr)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

aus |>
  # tibble gets us more compact printout
  tibble() |>
  # make sure points are correctyl sorted
  arrange(country, id, point_id) |>
  # convert to sf object
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "WGS84") |>
  # get elevation from Amazon Web Service Terrain Tiles
  get_elev_point(src = "aws") |> 
  # distance from previuos point to the current one, within the same id group
  mutate(dist = st_distance(geometry, lag(geometry), by_element = TRUE),
         # or switch from lag() to lead() to get distance to the next point
         # dist_to_next = st_distance(geometry, lead(geometry), by_element = TRUE),
         .by = id)
#> Mosaicing & Projecting
#> Note: Elevation units are in meters
#> Simple feature collection with 17 features and 6 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 129.251 ymin: -20.06129 xmax: 137.2865 ymax: -18.30723
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 17 × 7
#>       id country  point_id             geometry elevation elev_units   dist
#>  * <int> <chr>       <int>          <POINT [°]>     <dbl> <chr>         [m]
#>  1     1 Austral…        0  (130.1491 -19.5752)       382 meters        NA 
#>  2     1 Austral…        1  (129.9958 -19.4876)       425 meters     18788.
#>  3     1 Austral…        2 (129.7156 -19.25788)       444 meters     38941.
#>  4     1 Austral…        3 (129.7104 -19.20223)       441 meters      6212.
#>  5     2 Austral…        0  (129.251 -18.59016)       376 meters        NA 
#>  6     2 Austral…        1 (129.5436 -18.30723)       398 meters     44072.
#>  7     3 Austral…        0  (137.284 -20.06129)       229 meters        NA 
#>  8     3 Austral…        1 (137.2865 -20.04308)       234 meters      2042.
#>  9     3 Austral…        2 (137.1915 -20.00782)       237 meters     10671.
#> 10     3 Austral…        3  (137.122 -19.97166)       234 meters      8301.
#> 11     3 Austral…        4  (137.065 -19.91363)       235 meters      8783.
#> 12     3 Austral…        5 (136.8961 -19.85932)       235 meters     18665.
#> 13     4 Austral…        0 (136.8961 -19.85932)       235 meters        NA 
#> 14     4 Austral…        1 (136.8791 -19.88669)       235 meters      3525.
#> 15     4 Austral…        2 (136.8594 -19.91227)       233 meters      3512.
#> 16     4 Austral…        3 (136.8454 -19.92507)       233 meters      2042.
#> 17     4 Austral…        4  (136.836 -19.92976)       237 meters      1112.
```

Dataset example:

```r
aus <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
"id   country point_id      lon       lat
  1  Australia        0 130.1491 -19.57520
  1  Australia        1 129.9958 -19.48760
  1  Australia        2 129.7156 -19.25788
  1  Australia        3 129.7104 -19.20223
  2  Australia        0 129.2510 -18.59016
  2  Australia        1 129.5436 -18.30723
  3  Australia        0 137.2840 -20.06129
  3  Australia        1 137.2865 -20.04308
  3  Australia        2 137.1915 -20.00782
  3  Australia        3 137.1220 -19.97166
  3  Australia        4 137.0650 -19.91363
  3  Australia        5 136.8961 -19.85932
  4  Australia        0 136.8961 -19.85932
  4  Australia        1 136.8791 -19.88669
  4  Australia        2 136.8594 -19.91227
  4  Australia        3 136.8454 -19.92507
  4  Australia        4 136.8360 -19.92976")
```

---

Original answer - https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78251444/1